# webpack split chunks put everything in one file

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-splitchunks

I have large application, and I want split it.
Currently I have this structure:

```
application.js < entry point
Messages.js < application.js inner module
SystemSetup.js < application.js inner module
/node_modules/react.js < node modules
Common.js < local file, used inside of Messages and SystemSetup
```

Is it possible to split it into same chunks? I mean, I need to get

```
Common.js < module(chunk) with no dependencies
node_module.js < module(chunk) without dependencies
Messages.js < depends from Common and node_modules
SystemSetup.js < depends from Common and node_modules
application.js < depends from Messages and SystemSetup
```

Currently I made this webpack config file:

```
const path = require('path');
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
const AsyncChunkNames = require('webpack-async-chunk-names-plugin');
const Profile = require('./src/js/Profile');
const production = Profile.environment === 'prod';

module.exports = {
    mode: production ? 'production' : 'development',
    entry: {
        application: './src/js/Application.js',
        Messages: './src/js/components/routes/Messages.js',
        SystemSetup: './src/js/components/routes/SystemSetup.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets/js/'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: "/"
    },
    cache: true,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    watchOptions: {
        ignored: /node_modules/
    },
    plugins: [
        new WebpackNotifierPlugin({alwaysNotify: true, title: 'Webpack JS job'}),
        new AsyncChunkNames()
    ],
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            root: path.join(__dirname, 'src/js/'),
            '~': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/'),
        }
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: production ? {} : {
            cacheGroups: {
                default: false,
                vendors: false,
                node_modules: {
                    name: 'node_modules',
                    chunks: 'all',
                    test: /node_modules/,
                    priority: 40
                },
                common: {
                    name: 'common',
                    minChunks: 2,
                    chunks: 'all',
                    priority: 20,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true,
                    enforce: true
                },
                Messages: {
                    name: 'Messages',
                    chunks: 'all',
                    test: /.*\/Messages\.js$/,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true,
                    priority: 30
                },
                SystemSetup: {
                    name: 'SystemSetup',
                    chunks: 'all',
                    test: /.*\/SystemSetup\.js$/,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true,
                    priority: 30
                },
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I got all bundles - But result is not good. I have such files:

```
Common.js < 11mb files, expected around 5mb
node_module.js < 3.7 mb < looks good
Messages.js < 7kb, expected around 3mb
SystemSetup.js < 7kb, expected around 3mb
application.js < 7kb < looks good
```

Comment: why you haven't included `Common.js` in entries too?

Comment: 90% users load only `Messages.js`. Also, I want to compile only one module in time (when I work with Messages, I don't want to compile SystemSetup), most probably it will take smaller amount of time. Currently I have 8 separate modules, and compilation of all of them take around 3 minutes. If I work with `webpack --watch`, it take around 15 seconds to apply changes.I hope, with this changes I will be able to compile one module during 30 sec, and recompile with `webpack --watch` within 5 sec.

Comment: Are you using Redux?